# Unexpected delay after pushing view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, delay

I have tab bar controller, inside one of tabs I have 3 container view controllers. Only one can be presented, others are removed at the moment. Views for those controllers are defined in xib.

In one of those containers I have table view.

When I click on the cell I have to push view controller.

First time I launch app I have delay when pushing view controller. After I go back to table view and push again, there is no delay.

I print time when in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and in `viewDidLoad` of new controller, and delay is between 2 and 4 seconds.

This is code I use for pushing view controller:

```
EventDetailsViewController *eventDetailsVc = [[EventDetailsViewController alloc]init];
Events *event = [self.events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
eventDetailsVc.curentEvent = event;
NSDateFormatter *f2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[f2 setDateFormat:@"dd MMMM, hh:mm:ss.SSS a"];
NSLog([f2 stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:eventDetailsVc animated:YES];
});
```

Usually I don't use `dispatch_async` when pushing view controller, but this was one of suggested solutions I've found. I also tried `self.parentViewController.navigationController`, same results.

I don't know what to do about this delay, someone could help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps your main thread is blocked somehow, isn't it?

Comment: you are performing any task in init() or viewdidload() methods that blocks you main ui?

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I download data in viewDidAppear. You can see example in first answer comment.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the child view controller is the problem here. Make sure viewDidLoad / loadView don't start any expensive operations (like downloading data from the internet).

viewDidLoad & loadView only fire once, when the view controller is shown for the very first time. Once the view property is set, these methods won't fire anymore.

Any loading of content should be done on a background thread (perhaps using a library like AFNetworking) and should (usually) either start in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear.

Comment: Wolfgang, thank you for answer. In view did load i only assign delegate and data source of tableView to self. In viewDidAppear i download data from web. I don't use AFNetworking, I can't do that on this project. This is how i call web service

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError){

Comment: Disable the network code and see if the app is still so slow. If that's true, maybe there are some problems loading the xibs. Otherwise the issue is in the networking or parsing code.